Can I drill a hole vertically through this beam to run ethernet cable?
I have an ethernet cord in my upstairs bedroom (above the garage) that I want to drop down into the garage. Ideally through the inside of the wall. I drilled a small test hole through the bedroom subfloor and out through the garage ceiling to see where I should drill up from the garage to open a hole inside the wall to do my run:

However, this made me realize that the hole in the garage would have to go through what looks like a very load-bearing beam or set of beams:


I want to drill a 3/8" hole all the way up through this beam, but I think it might weaken the structural integrity. Can I drill the hole and reinforce the wood with some steel plates? Or would I be okay just drilling the hole as-is?
Any other suggestions to get this wire down into the garage?

Aside: Garage walls and ceilings are usually fire rated to slow the spread of fire into living spaces. You don't want to compromise that. (And it makes sense that the bedroom wall would be bearing on a beam across the garage.)

Second that. My friends entire house burned down due to a fire in the garage. Also, as a general rule of thumb, avoid drilling through or cutting anything structural.

I have a fire sprinkler system so I'm not terribly worried about that part, I'm mainly concerned about the structural integrity. I will consider drilling at an angle so I only go through a small portion of the beam

Personally, I'd recommend cutting a large hole adjacent to the beam, a) for getting eyes on it, and b) for working room.  https://www.constructionspecifier.com/a-guide-to-field-notching-and-drilling-lvl-and-glulam/2/  Worst case, run the cable in some surface mount molding or race—it's only a garage.

drill the hole on an angle so that you miss the beam.
If you go in at 45 degrees you can add the thinkness of the subfloor and floor to the existing wall thickness (measured at the baseboard).
Assuming you just want the wire to be invisible and not nailproof, if you want nailproof drill a slighly larger hole and insert a steel tube.

The beam is pretty massive, but I think I know what you mean. I'll try to calculate the angle and distance I need to start my entrance hole from to exit through the wall where I want it, that way less of the beam is drilled

you don't need to hit the bottom plate. even if  your drill goes through the baseboard and drywall noone will know it  I wuuld poke something into the small hole you drilled  and feel for the side of the beam to see how much space there is,

Using a thinner ethernet cable is another option,   I have some 4mm diameter cat6 patch cables here;
